# Trying to get an int value from a String with Enum::Parse

Tags: .net, managed-c++

I am working with C++ and .NET 1.1, and need to parse String values into their corresponding int values from an enumerator.

I have an enumerator

```
__value static enum myEnum {
  VALUE1,
  VALUE2,
  VALUE3
};
```

and I am trying to do something along the lines of

```
int value = (int)Enum::Parse(__typeof(myEnum), stringToParse);
```

or

```
int value = (myEnum)Enum::Parse(__typeof(myEnum), stringToParse);
```

except of course that `Enum::Parse` returns an `Object*`, and I just can't work out how to cast that object into an `int`.

What am I doing wrong? (Something to do with managed extensions, like last time I got stuck?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be an unbox - although you *might* want to unbox to the enum and then cast. In C#, something like;

```
int value = (int)(myEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnum), stringToParse);
```

Not sure what that looks like in C++ though.

In C# the following *also* works, but I can't guarantee how formally:

```
int value = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(myEnum), stringToParse);
```

Note in the above I'm assuming that `myEnum` is using `Int32` as the underlying type. If that is *not* the case, then you need tweak it to unbox as the correct underlying type *first*.

Running it through reflector, I get:

```
 Int32 __gc* value = *static_cast<__box Int32*>(
   *static_cast<__box myEnum*>(Enum::Parse(__typeof(myEnum), stringToParse)));
```

Comment: Slight tweak on that last code snippet got it to work. int value = (int)(*static_cast<__box myEnum*>(Enum::Parse(__typeof(myEnum), stringToParse))); Thank you. =)